# How to recursive search for a file, but excluding one folder from search using Python

Tags: python, glob

I have something like :

```
folder__
       |_folder1
       |_folder2_
       |         |_folder2.1
       |_folder3
```

I need to search for a file **file.txt** in recursive way  in my main folder, but excluding the **folder1** from search.
i.e. i need to search in folder2, folder2.1 and folder3.

Comment: Use `os.walk()`, and in your loop use an `if` statement that checks if the directory is `folder1` and skips it.

Comment: How ? I try something like : for root, dirs, files in os.walk(scr):

    
    if os.path.basename(root)=='folder1':
        continue                                                                                                                                         but it keep search in folder1..... How use this if statement in os.walk ?

Comment: That won't work if you have folders nested inside `folder1`, because `root` will be `folder/folder1/nestedfolder`, and the basename will be `nestedfolder`.

Comment: Use `if root.startswith('folder/folder1')`

Comment: IF u want u can add that comments as answer , and i will approve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `os.walk()` loop, check if the folder is `folder1` and skip it.

```
for for root, dirs, files in os.walk(scr):
    if root.startswith(os.path.join(scr, "folder1")):
        continue
    # rest of code
```